# How to map multidimensional arrays in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm a  bit new to scala spark. I couldn't find any answer regarding this. I have a array like this

```
   |Id           |endpoints                         |score|          |type|

|106688      |[[clothes:tops], [clothes]]        |[[0.01], [0.283]]     |[S1S2, S1]   |
|107594      |[[clothes,tops], [clothes]]        |[[0.01], [0.19]]      |[S1S2, S1]   |
|108800      |[[clothes:tops], [clothes]]        |[[0.01], [0.052]]     |[S1S2, S1]   |
```

I need to map this into each other as in below format.

```
Map(S1S2 -> Map(clothes:tops -> 0.01)
```

What is the best approach to mapping records of this array.Basically I need to know how to zip fields as in below format.

```
 Map(S1S2 -> Map(clothes:tops -> 0.01), S1 -> Map(clothes -> 0.25))
```

Comment: This is a very difficult question to follow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself. Hope answer of this will helpful for others too.
Basically what I had to use map function. I'll put my code lines here.

```
   df.map(r =>{
              val Id = r.getAs[String]("Id")
              val endpoints = r.getAs[Seq[String]]("endpoints")
              val score =   r.getAs[Seq[Seq[Double]]]("score")
              val type = r.getAs[Seq[Seq[String]]]("type")
              val zipped = endpoint zip scores
              val merge = zipped.map{
                r =>
                  val endpoint = r._1
                val score = r._2
                 endpoint zip(score)
              }
   val seqmerged = merge.map(r => (r.toMap))
          val endpointmerged = endpointValue zip seqmerged
          (atgId, endpointmerge.toString())
```